# Long institute title in Madrid theme of beamer class

Tags: beamer, header-footer, titles

I use the `beamer` documentclass with the `Madrid` theme and the `beetle` color theme. My institute name is too long for the footer, so I'd love to use the long name on the title slide and a shortened version ("Universität Bonn") in the footer. Is there any way to do this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\title{Donald Knuth}
\author{...}
\institute{Rheinische Friedrich-Wilhelms-Universit\"{a}t Bonn}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beetle}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{Blubb...}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the optional argument for `\institute`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\title{Donald Knuth}
\author{...}
\institute[Universität Bonn]{Rheinische Friedrich-Wilhelms-Universit\"{a}t Bonn}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beetle}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\frame{Blubb...}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One should emphasize that this is very useful and general option for shortening various items.